# How can I download python libraries with Basket if I am behind a proxy?

Tags: python, pip

I have a Linux machine with no internet connection and a windows machine with an internet connection. I would like to download two python libraries with [Basket](https://pypi.org/project/Basket/) on my Windows machine and then download them with my Linux machine via [Basket](https://pypi.org/project/Basket/) so I can run a python script.

I tried to download the packages with basket but it gives me errors and I can't find in the documentation the command to download with proxy

I would like to download libraries with basket thru proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Basket/) and checking the [source code](https://github.com/dbaty/Basket/blob/master/basket/main.py), I could not find a way to do this via Basket.

You could try to enforce the routing of ALL your traffic from the Windows machine to the proxy with tools like [freecap](http://www.freecap.ru/), [proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/), [proxycap](http://www.proxycap.com/), and configure to run behind the python executable. However, be aware that this would reroute ALL your connections, not just for Basket, python etc.